# Excel Command Button to Simultaneously Check and Uncheck certain Active-X checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use an Active-X Command button in Excel to select certain checkboxes and deselect others simultaneously. As it stands right now, I wish to uncheck all boxes that start with or contain the name "Design" while checking all those that start with or contain the name "Checkbox".

The code below was working for the unchecking of boxes that have "Design" in their name, but ever since I have added the checking of boxes starting with "Checkbox", I receive an error (Method "Name" of object'_OLEOBJECT' Failed).

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim o As Object
        For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            If InStr(1, o.Name, "Design") > 0 Then
                o.Object.Value = False
            ElseIf InStr(1, o.Name, "CheckBox") < 1 Then
                    o.Object.Value = True
            End If
        Next                      
    End Sub
```

I have also tried this variation which still results in the same error as the above:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim o As Object
        For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            If InStr(1, o.Name, "Design") > 0 Then
                o.Object.Value = False
            End If
        Next

    Dim j As Object
         For Each j In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
             If InStr(1, j.Name, "CheckBox") < 1 Then
                j.Object.Value = True
            End If
        Next


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it unchecks all checkboxes. Just set it to true if you want to check all checkboxes.

```
Sub uncheck_all()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "CheckBox" Then sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object = True    'set to true if you want to check all checkboxes
        End If
        If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If sh.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then sh.OLEFormat.Object = True    'set to true if you want to check all checkboxes
        End If
    Next sh
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If o.Name Like "Design*" Then 'use  If o.Name Like "*Design*" Then if you want to be any name with "Design" in the name.
            o.Object.Value = False
        End If
    Next o
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my initial description. Essentially, I have a list of 200 or so checkboxes, which allows the user to make selections based on various scenarios. That being said, I want a button which will return the user to the default (my proposed) scenario. Thus when the user clicks the command button, I want all boxes that contain the name "Design" to be unchecked while all checkboxes that contain the name "Checkbox" to be checked such that it returns to the default scenario.

Comment: try updated post, this should do what you want, unchecks all other checkboxes but leaves checkboxes with the name "Design" as not checked.

Comment: @pokeman_Man This essentially works as I want it to, but there is one problem why it still isn't working. The name "Design" takes many variations such as "Design1" or "Design2" so each Checkbox has it's own unique name, but each one I want selected off does contain "Design" in it. Would you know how to check if the Checkbox name contains "Design" rather than is exactly "Design"? This would completely solve my issue

Comment: try updated post, it should now take any checkbox starting with the name "Design" so whether it  be "Design1", "Design23", ect.